# No known class method for selector 'generatorWithWorld:'

Tags: ios, xcode, class, methods

I'm trying to create a platform game on xcode and this my first ever project and I've came across this error and it says "No known class method for selector 'generatorWithWorld:'" and i'm also getting the error "No visible @interface for 'HSWorldGenerator' declares the selector 'populate'"

This is the code for MyScene.h:

```
//
//  MyScene.h
//  The Adventure of Colin The Sloth
//

//  Copyright (c) 2014 SunnersCorp. All rights reserved.
//

**#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "HSWorldGenerator.h"**

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@end
```

MyScence.m:

```
//
//  MyScene.m
//  The Adventure of Colin The Sloth
//
//  Created by Harpreet Sunner on 24/07/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 SunnersCorp. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyScene.h"
#import "HSSloth.h"


@interface MyScene()
@property BOOL isStarted;
@property BOOL isGameOver;
@end

@implementation MyScene
{
    HSSloth *Sloth;
    SKNode *world;
    HSWorldGenerator *generator;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5, 0.5);
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        world = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:world];

        generator = [HSWorldGenerator generatorWithWorld:world]; **THIS IS WHERE I GET THE FIRST ERROR**
        [self addChild:generator];
        [generator populate]; **THIS IS WHERE I GET THE SECOND ERROR**


        Sloth = [HSSloth Sloth];
        [world addChild:Sloth];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    self.isStarted = YES;
    [Sloth start];
}

-(void)clear
{
    NSLog(@"clear method called");
}

- (void)gameOver
{
    NSLog(@"gameOver method called");
}

- (void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self centerOrNode:Sloth];
}

- (void)centerOrNode:(SKNode *)node
{
    CGPoint postionInScene = [self convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];
    world.position = CGPointMake(world.position.x - postionInScene.x, world.position.y);
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.isStarted)
        [self start];
    else if (self.isGameOver)
        [self clear];
    else
        [Sloth jump];

}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

HSWorldGenerator.h:

```
//
//  HSWorldGenerator.h
//  The Adventure of Colin The Sloth
//
//  Created by Harpreet Sunner on 24/07/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 SunnersCorp. All rights reserved.
//

#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>


@interface HSWorldGenerator : SKNode

+ (id)generatorWithWorld:(SKNode *)world;
- (void)populate;
- (void)generate;


@end
```

HSWorldGenerator.m:

```
//
//  HSWorldGenerator.m
//  The Adventure of Colin The Sloth
//
//  Created by Harpreet Sunner on 24/07/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 SunnersCorp. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HSWorldGenerator.h"

@interface HSWorldGenerator ()
@property double currentGroundX;
@property double currentObstacleX;
@property SKNode *world;
@end

@implementation HSWorldGenerator

+ (id)generatorWithWorld:(SKNode *)world
{
    HSWorldGenerator *generator = [HSWorldGenerator node];
    generator.currentGroundX = 0;
    generator.currentObstacleX = 400;
    generator.world = world;
    return generator;
}

- (void)populate
{
    for (int i = 0; 1 <3; i++)
        [self generate];
}

- (void)generate
{
    SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.scene.frame.size.width, 100)];
    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.currentGroundX, -self.scene.frame.size.height/2 + ground.frame.size.height/2);
    ground.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ground.size];
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self.world addChild:ground];

    self.currentGroundX += ground.frame.size.width;

    SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 70)];
    obstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.currentObstacleX, ground.position.y + ground.frame.size.height/2 + obstacle.frame.size.height/2);
    obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obstacle.size];
    obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    [self.world addChild:obstacle];

    self.currentObstacleX += 250;

}
@end
```

Could anyone please tell me what ive done wrong and how I can fix this please, I will appreciate it so much.

Thank You!

Comment: Please post relevant code & a question explaining the problem you're having & what you've tried to fix it. People aren't likely to  download a random project and dig through it for you.

Comment: ive edited it now, thank you for letting me know. I how you can understand my problem and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check where you `#import HSWorldGenerator.h` into your MyScene.h file.
The error is telling you that it doesn't know where to find the class method.
Looks like where you try to import the header in MyScene.h you have extra '**'s that might be commenting out that line.

Comment: The extra ** arent in the actual code, I think that was put in by accident when writing the question...  but ive checked the MyScence.h file and everything in there is fine but i dont know why it is doing it

Comment: Hmm ... In that case the code here looks as if it should recognize the class name & class methods just fine ... Maybe "Clean" the project? Or try importing HSWorldGenerator.h to your MyScene.m instead - there's no reason to announce other dependencies in MyScene.h anyway. If those don't work, all I can suggest is close/restart XCode - sometimes it just refuses to recognize import statements - I've run into that before.

Comment: I've tried cleaning the project but still no luck at all. and I've tried importing HSWorldGenerator.h to your MyScene.m and that still doesn't fix anything. I've close/restarted it many time too but still no luck.